# Running setup-node@v3 on Macos-12 in Github Actions installs darwin x64 of Node instead of M1. How can I force M1?

Tags: github-actions, node-gyp

I am using the below action yml file. When the action runs the x64 version of node is installed instead of M1 how can I force it to run the arm64 version of Node? The message I can see of the Node version is "gyp info using node@18.14.1 | darwin | x64" (I'm also running node-gyp)

```
name: test-keyring-go
on: [push]
jobs:
  build-native-node-module-on-mac:
    runs-on: macos-12
    environment: dev
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'          
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version: '1.20.1'      
      - run: npm install --ignore-scripts
      - run: npm run build:go:m1
      - run: npm run build:node:m1
      - run: npm run test
      - run: npm run vitest
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the GHA-hosted macOS runner is M1 (ARM64)?

Comment: Initially that is what I assumed, but the more I try it it appears that its actually x64. I guess their M1 based runners are not out yet? Anyway to confirm this as their docs aren't specific

Comment: Yes, GHA-hosted M1 runners are not supported at the moment. However, you can use a self-hosted mcaOS M1 runner. See https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-09-github-actions-self-hosted-runners-now-support-apple-m1-hardware/.